# How to short down this code to create django model so it works the same in term of functionality

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

**Just imagine Netflix Site, I want to store video links of multiple seasons of TV shows with multiple episodes, I want to increment number of seasons and episode of a certain tv show on the need specifically from admin area. I don't know ho to do that instead of just creating variable of every episode link and season model. Please Help ! Thanx in adv**

```
class Tv_Shows(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
        unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    episode1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    episode2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    episode3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    episode4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    episode5 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    episode6 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    episode7 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    episode8 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    episode9 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    episode10 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    
    imdb_rating = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=1)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
        default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',

                        args=[self.publish.year,
                        self.publish.month,
                        self.publish.day, self.slug])

    

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.   
    published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Comment: Create an `Episode` model with a foreign key to the show.

Comment: Oh .. Yes, Thank You , h

Comment: any other way to do within this model @KlausD.

Comment: creating a tree like model for the number of seasons and number of episodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `Episode` model with a foreign key which represents the show.
this would be the normal db design and you don't need to alter your model every time.

This is how it would look like.

```py
class TvShow(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    
    imdb_rating = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=1)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])    

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.   
    published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

```py
class Episode(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    show = models.ForeignKey(TvShow, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='episodes')
    
    ...
    objects = models.Manager()
```

If an episode can have more than one tv-show as it's parent, then you can go for a [many to many field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Now, to access all the episodes that a show has, you can do

```py
tv_show = TvShow.objects.get(**kwargs)
tv_show.episode_set
# returns a django queryset object
```

relevant docs regarding the same is here:
[django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: Thanx for the answer @CosmicReindeer

Comment: am glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table `episode`, create a one-to-many relationship between the two tables.

Comment: thanx for the answer @chseng

Answer (score 0):

Think like this:

Episodes has the main content. Seasons and Tv show details are just the meta data. So start from the main content (very small child).

```
Episodes > Seasons > Tv Show
```

So how the database design looks like:

```
Class TvShow(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

    def get_all_seasons(self):
        return self.tv_show_seasons.all().order_by('-created') # all seasons for particular tv show

Class Season(models.Model):
    tv_show = models.ForeignKey('TvShow', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tv_show_seasons')
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

    def get_all_episodes(self):
        return self.season_episodes.all().order_by('-created') # all episodes for a particular season

Class Episode(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey('Season', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='season_episodes')
    ...
```

This is the suggestive approach to do it.

Comment: Thank You @Siva Sankar  That's seems much interesting approach

Comment: I am Happy to help.